# Links not opening in default browser in linux mint

Tags: linux, browser, linux-mint, default-settings

I have Brave set as my default browser. But when I try to open links from some documents or from some app, they open in Firefox.

Comment: "Some" links... are those to MIME types such as "pdf" that you've set to be opened by your browser???

Comment: @DrMoishePippik In the preferred applications, I have set Brave. I dont know about the rest. As said, If i open links from my mail reader or any other app, they open in firefox